# How far from the water intakes and drain do the receptacles for a stackable washer/dryer have to be and does code require a GFI?

Tags: electrical, water

How far from the water intakes & drain do the receptacles for a stackable washer/Electric dryer need to be and does code require a GFI?

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: I'd like to reiterate @ThreePhaseEel's question.  It is really difficult to get the plug out of the socket for my washing machine because it is obstructed by the water pipe coming out of the tap (faucet) which is *immediately* above.  This is in Germany, and I am pretty sure it was legal in 1997 - but I am equally sure it was crazy even then.

Answer (score 2):

The 2017 NEC does not specify minimum separation. In a dwelling unit 125v receptacles in laundry areas require GFCI protection. In other than dwelling units laundry areas are not specified, but within 6' of a sink 150v to ground or less single phase receptacles 50A or less and 3 phase receptacles 100A or less also requires GFCI protection. (Each leg of a 240v circuit is less than 150v to ground.)

Answer (score 0):

This claims to meet UPC code in the USA:(and I think answers your question regarding distance)

https://www.zoro.com/guy-gray-outlet-box-washing-machine-12-in-mip-82033/i/G0476463/

(Not that I would pay THAT price for it).

Comment: UPC = Universal Product Code (i.e. the bar-code on every product sold)? It may meet code, assuming it's connected to a GFCI _breaker_ since this isn't a GFCI outlet. Side note: the item in their picture looks _well_ used! Yikes!

Comment: I think that UPC, since listed as a standard here, is "uniform plumbing code". Yes it is not a GFCI  outlet. Perhaps the product preceded the NEC change requiring GFCI for laundry outlet?

Comment: Ah. I was unaware of _that_ UPC. thanks! It is important to note that "meeting code when the product was designed" does not equate to "meeting code when the product was installed".